# jQuery Mobile makes page jump 1 pixel on load

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm currently building a responsive website based on the jQuery Mobile framework (version 1.3.2). Everything I need seems to work properly (panel menus, fixed header, AJAX page loading), except for one little thing that's driving me completely nuts: jQuery Mobile makes the page jump 1 pixel on every load. It does not happen in Mobile Safari, but in Chrome and Safari on the desktop.

I did some research online and I found out that

```
$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = 0;
```

solves the 1 pixel problem in Chrome and Safari on the desktop, but creates the 1 pixel problem in Mobile Safari. Is this a common jQuery Mobile problem? Why does it happen and how can I get rid of it on all devices?

Thanks a million!